# Root access amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, root

Hey guys, I am very new to linux, and amazon-ec2.  I wanted to put a quick server.
For some reason, when I sign in with my key pair, it prompts me for a username, I input ec2-user, and I'm in.
The problem is that I don't have root access (and can't find the root password).
I need to install screen to run the server in the background, and also create a new user, that doesn't have root, to run the server.  Neither of which I can do without root..
Any help?

Edit:
I am using Basic 32-bit Amazon Linux AMI 2010.11.1 Beta as the 'AMI'.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Amazon Linux AMI User Guide explains that you can use sudo to run commands as root e.g. `sudo whoami`:

http://ec2-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonLinuxAMIUserGuide.pdf

> **How do I get root SSH access on my Amazon Linux AMI instance?**
>
> The Amazon Linux AMI does not allow remote
>   root SSH by default. You should
>   specify a keypair at instance launch
>   and login as ‘ec2‐user’ using your
>   keypair to access the command line.
>   This user has sudo access by default
>   to allow you to run root actions. If
>   you wish to enable remote root login,
>   please be aware that it is
>   significantly less secure than relying
>   on keypairs and a secondary user.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't found that haha `sudo su -` works.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Linux image you're running, but generally you can sudo from the initial login user account to gain root privileges.

Comment: Forgot that bit, edited above post

Answer (score 0):

Has worked for me connecting to ssh -i jose.pem **root**@ec2-46-137-38-52.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: This really barely qualifies as an answer, if it even does.